# Logarithm of Grassmann numbers

Tags: fermions, calculus, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

What is $\log \theta$ where $\theta$ is a Grassmann number such that $\theta^2 = 0$. How does one then look at its logarithm? Does it even make sense?

Comment: No, it does not make mathematical sense. Where did you encounter it?

Comment: @Qmechanic I have not encountered it anywhere but there is a chance of seeing it when doing Gaussian integral over grassmann numbers. The $M$ in $\det{M}$, which appears due to the gaussian integral, if treated as a matrix over grassman variable will lead to such objects if one uses $\det{M} = \exp(tr(\ln M))$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In general, if $f: \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is a [complex analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function) function, then we can define the value
   $$ f(z)~:=~ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0} \frac{f^{(n)}(z_B)}{n!}z_S^n\tag{1.1.6}$$ to a [supernumber](https://planetmath.org/supernumber) $$z~=~\underbrace{z_B}_{\text{body}}+\underbrace{z_S}_{\text{soul}}\tag{1.1.2}$$
   if the body
   $$z_B~\in~\Omega$$
   belongs to the open neighborhood $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{C}$.
2. The problem with OP's example $\log\theta$ is that the body of the [Grassmann number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number) $\theta$ is $0$, but $f=\log$ is not defined in $0\notin \Omega$, so we cannot apply definition (1.1.6).

References:

1. Bryce DeWitt, *Supermanifolds,* Cambridge Univ. Press, 1992.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think we can assign a meaningful value to $\log(\theta)$. We can, however, find $\log(1+\theta)$ as follows.

Since $\theta^2=0$ then we have $\theta^k=0 \space \forall k \ge 2$. So

$\displaystyle\exp(\theta) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {\theta^k}{k!} = 1 + \theta$

and since $\log$ is the inverse of $\exp$ we have

$\log(1 + \theta) = \log(\exp(\theta)) = \theta$